# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 (http request)

Tags: flutter, indexing, get, range, dropdown

i'm a beginner in flutter and
i have a problem with my http request, when i wanna add in my DropdownButton this http request (that i put in the list called deviceGet) or even print it to see it : i have this error :

```
RangeError(index) : Invalid value : Valid value range is empty : 0
```

This is all the error message :

```
 Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building Builder:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp 
package:chat/main.dart:180
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:60)
#1      _MyListScreenState.initState 
package:chat/main.dart:226
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4428
#3      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4274
#4      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3269
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 591 libraries in 363ms.
flutter: 0

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building Builder:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp 
package:chat/main.dart:180
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:60)
#1      _MyListScreenState.initState 
package:chat/main.dart:225
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4428
#3      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4274
#4      Element.inflateWidget
```

I don't understand this error because i can see my request if i put in the body

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: deviceGet.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
                title: Text("Num $index " + device[index].commands[0].id));
         title: Text("Num $index " + deviceGet[index].name));
```

or if i put

```
Text(deviceGet[0].name)
```

but with warning

This is my code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Get.dart';
import 'Device.dart';
import 'Commands.dart';
import 'deviceData.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyListScreenState();
}

class _MyListScreenState extends State {
  //
  List<deviceData> dataDevice = deviceData.getDevicesData();

  List<DropdownMenuItem<deviceData>> listDropDevice;
  deviceData deviceSelection;
  //

  var deviceGet = new List<Device>();

  GetDevice() {
    GET.getDevice().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        deviceGet = list.map((model) => Device.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GetDevice();

    //print(deviceGet[0].name);

    // add in the dropDown
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
      print(i);
      dataDevice.add(deviceData("Device" + i.toString()));
      dataDevice.add(deviceData(deviceGet[0].name));
      i = i + 1;
    }

    listDropDevice = buildDropdownMenuItems(dataDevice);
    deviceSelection = listDropDevice[0].value;
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<deviceData>> buildDropdownMenuItems(List devices) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<deviceData>> items = List();
    for (deviceData device1 in devices) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: device1,
          child: Text(device1.name),
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  onChange(deviceData selectionUtilisateur) {
    setState(() {
      deviceSelection = selectionUtilisateur;
    });
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Device List"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          //Text(deviceGet[0].name),
          DropdownButton(
            value: deviceSelection,
            items: listDropDevice,
            onChanged: onChange,
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetDevice() is asynchronous** method so it takes time to get data from json and in the begging **deviceGet** is empty, so it gives error of range.

you can make GetDevice() method asynchronous using await and async* and while calling that method use .then method and then access values.

also, make sure that you are getting data in GetDevice metod.

Comment: It didn't work, i tried to make it like you suggested and i also tried to make an asynchronous method as you can see.

Comment: And i'm sure that i'm getting data in GetDevice method because i tried.

Comment: testeAsync().then((){
        // access dataDevice over here
    });

Answer (score 0):

I already had a similar problem.
The Problem is within the for loop.

In place of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
  print(i);
  dataDevice.add(deviceData("Device" + i.toString()));
  dataDevice.add(deviceData(deviceGet[0].name));
  i = i + 1;
}

listDropDevice = buildDropdownMenuItems(dataDevice);
deviceSelection = listDropDevice[0].value;
}
```

change it to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
  print(i);
  dataDevice.add(deviceData("Device" + i.toString()));
  dataDevice.add(deviceData(deviceGet[i].name));
  i = i + 1;
}

listDropDevice = buildDropdownMenuItems(dataDevice);
deviceSelection = listDropDevice[i].value;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Only answers to the question should be posted as andwer, not questions or comments. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.